# Force Image Flush Left

Tags: html, css

No matter what I try there is always space to the left of my image.  I've stripped everything out and below is a picture. Chrome's css inspector is saying the body is inheriting a margin-left of 8 px; (see picture below)  Is there any way to make the image flush against the left edge?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <img src="../images/warn.png"/>
</html>
```

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

```
position:absolute
```

then you can specify left,right, top, bottom

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have default styles built in - try overriding the margin in your CSS (that is to say, just set it to `0px`).

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```